# Google Map " but your computer or network may be sending automated queries" error

Tags: php, google-maps

I've a PHP project that use to work like a cake but now google map api is blocking it

I user a code as this one to get geolocation data from google map (address to coordinates transformation) with a low number of request/day.

```
$base_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=".KEY."&q=".urlencode($address);
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($request_url);
```

with KEY ad my google API key but I started to get this error

> We're sorry...
>   ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

how can I fix that ? Google API guide is useless...

Answer (score 0):

Most of Google Api's have rate limiting protections. You should read the terms of service and see the allowed policy.

Besides that, what you could technically do (and i'm almost certain you are running than code in a loop for multiple addresses) is set a random delay (more than 20s) between the calls to google api, limiting the load and your own evilness... You could also think about using curl to make requests with multiple user agents... its technically possible, although frowned upon :)